# Can't bind application.properties file in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, application.properties

I am trying to bind the values in my application.properties file in my Springboot application to my external config class.

I am using the @Value annotation to mark the variable I want passed in from application.properties file and my application.properties file looks like this

```
server.port=9000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
app.developerName = "f21ad267-e241-4ed0-8943-721fa90bcf3a"
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated as I haven't got very far with the springboot documentation and I am unsure of what I am doing wrong

Comment: Don’t post screenshots of your code please!

Comment: `@Value` will be available **after** object construction. You are accesssing it inside the constructor, which won't work because the value is only available afterwards.

Comment: I try calling the get value method elsewhere in my code but still returned null

Comment: Might be because developerName is static

Comment: you sure application.properties is in your classpath ?

Comment: @georgesvan where do I declare my class path? This is something I am unsure of

Comment: the application.properties should be right under src/main/resource. Apparently yours is under the com package.

Comment: @georgesvan I wasn't where to put it so I placed two application.properties files in two folders

Comment: you should read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160419/spring-boot-classpath