# What is classpath in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am very new to Spring. I don't know what is the path of the `classpath`. Like from the project structure generated by Intellij, which folder is the classpath root? My guess is the `resources/` folder

I have included an image of my project structure

Thank you very much!

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c81oj.png)

Comment: Please have a look to this Question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160419/spring-boot-classpath:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160419/spring-boot-classpath)