# Where do I put my resource file to make it readable in Spring using classpath?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, classpath, java-resources

I'm trying to load a text file with Java, Maven & Spring, following the examples at

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access#3-using-resourceloader

Also using this guide as the base for my application and structure

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

The Baeldung guide uses code like this to create a `Resource`

```
resourceLoader.getResource(
  "classpath:data.txt");
```

And when I run this code, I get an IOException

```
class path resource [data.txt] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

What the guide doesn't say is where I need to put this file to make it available.

I suppose classpath is a path relative to the class, in this case "HelloController.java"

In my project file structure, this class is located at `src/main/java/com/example/demo/HelloController.java`

so I put the text file at `src/main/resources/com/example/demo/data.txt` which is not working. Where does the file need to be to make it readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helped by this post [Spring Boot classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160419/spring-boot-classpath) I tried to put the file directly in the "resources" folder, and then it worked.

`src/main/resources/data.txt`